# Run async/await method on other than UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, entity-framework, async-await

I have a WPF app with an EF connection to a database. But when I call await `DbSet().SingleAsync()` my UI thread is stuck and not responsive. I figured out that when I ran await it will still run on main UI thread so I can access UI. That will explain why it is working when I use only `Task.Delay()`, because `SingleAsync` is using thread, but `Task.Delay()` doesn't.
`ConfigureAwait(false)` should solve this and run it on different thread. But it doesn't and my UI still freeze.

Am I doing it wrong ?

Code:

```
private async void Button_Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   await userService.ValidateCredentials(textBoxLogin.Text, textBoxLogin.Text).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public async Task<bool> ValidateCredentials(string username, string password)
{
    User user = await userDao.SingleOrNull(true, o => o.Username == username && o.Password == password);

    if (user == null)
        return (false);
    return (true);
}

public async Task<ResourceDbType> SingleOrNull(bool noTracking, Expression<Func<ResourceDbType, bool>> where)
{
    ResourceDbType ret;
    try
    {
        if (noTracking)
        {
            ret = await GetDbSet().AsNoTracking().SingleAsync(where);
        }
        else
            ret = await GetDbSet().SingleAsync(where);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

EDIT:
BaseDao should only expose functions from DbContext with selected DbSet model registered at MainDbContext. We are using this code at work at RestApi service, so I reused it because I am used to it.

`[RegisterClass(Lifetime.Scoped)]` is atribute for marking class to Register it in DependencyInjection at start of app with reflection.

Dao code:

```
public class BaseDao<ResourceDbType> : IDisposable where ResourceDbType : class, new()
{
 public DbContext DbContext { get; protected set; }

 public BaseDao(MainDbContext mainDbContext)
 {
  DbContext = mainDbContext;
 }
 public DbSet<ResourceDbType> GetDbSet()
 {
  return this.DbContext.Set<ResourceDbType>();
 }
        
 public List<ResourceDbType> ToList()
 {
  return this.GetDbSet().ToList();
 }

 public ResourceDbType[] ToArray()
 {
 return this.GetDbSet().ToArray();
 }
 public async Task<ResourceDbType> SingleOrNull(bool noTracking, Expression<Func<ResourceDbType, bool>> where)
 {
 ResourceDbType ret;
 try
  {
   if (noTracking)
   {
    ret = await GetDbSet().AsNoTracking().SingleAsync(where);
   }
   else
    ret = await GetDbSet().SingleAsync(where);
   }
  catch (Exception ex)
   {
    return null;
   }
 return ret;
}

public void Dispose()
 {
  this.DbContext?.Dispose();
 }
}
```

UserDao Code:

```
[RegisterClass(Lifetime.Scoped)]
public class UserDao : BaseDao<User>
{
 public UserDao(MainDbContext mainDbContext) : base(mainDbContext)
 {

 }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `private async Task Button_Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` instead of `private async void Button_Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`?

Comment: @Delphi.Boy no it should be an async void

Comment: Also to the OP there are a lot of assumptions here, and a lot of them are misinformed or incorrect

Comment: There is no classic deadlock problem here (in the code shown). There is likely more to the story, but it hard to know where based on the current code

Comment: @Andy I tried ConfigureAwait everywhere but with the same result.

Comment: @MichaelRandall Yes, I was afraid I got theory wrong, I am grasping at straws here. Could you please elaborate on what is incorrect? 

I am not sure what other code could explained it. It is almost a blank app. I have a default blank main window where I call Show() on the Login view with 2 textboxes and 1 button. 
But I am using DependencyInjection service, could I use it wrong so it would disrupt await/async somehow?

Comment: My gut feeling is there is something fishy about your methods, like DbSet can paste the code to this.

Comment: Can you paste the code to this? Sorry phone typo...

Comment: @MichaelRandall I added code for Dao to question.

Comment: Ahh ok, there is still not really any reason *i can see* for the UI to be blocked. Maybe someone with fresh eyes will pick something up

Answer (score 3):

Async is not a silver bullet, and from what I see from the example, it is most likely unnecessary. Async is not ideal for "use everywhere, every time" but rather for *potentially* mitigating expensive operations.

By tucking away EF behind a service and then a repository makes your EF operations a lot less efficient than they could be.

For example: Without a repository level. (Trust EF to be used by the service, and injected into the service)

```
// UI
private void Button_Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var result = userService.ValidateCredentials(textBoxLogin.Text, textBoxLogin.Text);
}

// Service
public bool ValidateCredentials(string username, string password)
{
    var result = Context.Users.Any(x => x.UserName == userName && x.Password == password);
    return result;
}
```

EF can generate a very efficient `EXISTS` query rather than loading an entity just to check if a row exists. Faster code without needing to worry about handing it off.

If you want to be able to unit test the service, then you can introduce a repository. I recommend leveraging `IQueryable`:

```
// Service
public bool ValidateCredentials(string username, string password)
{
    using (var unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
    {
        var result = UserRepository.FindUserByName(username, password).Any();
        return result;
    }
}

// Repository
public IQueryable<User> FindUserByName(string userName, string password)
{
    var query = Context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == userName && x.Password == password);
    return query;
}
```

The repository can guard access to the Entities to ensure required rules are followed etc. yet can be more easily mocked out than the DbContext. This requires consideration for scoping the DbContext in a Unit of Work to facilitate the Service to control the boundary of the DbContext and interact with the resulting entities returned by the Repository. The implementation I use for that with EF is Medhime's DbContextScope. (There are forks available for EF Core) This gives the service full control over how the entities are consumed with the repository enforcing the rules and making mocking simpler.

Side Note: Some devs don't like that the services need to be aware of EF concerns (such as legal Lambdas that EF can understand) but this is a trade off for a thinner, much more flexible Repository. (Handling additional criteria, projection, sorting, paging, etc. is a snap however a particular consumer needs.)  I've seen many attempts to abstract away EF to accept criteria, sorting, projection, and paging into repository methods using Func etc. but the reality is that these are quite complex and still have to adhere to EF's rules anyways. Ultimately when you choose to use EF you need to trust it as part of your solution in order to leverage it to it's fullest.

Async is geared more towards particularly expensive operations. WPF's synchronization context essentially supports interacting with async code, but since this is going to ensure code resumes on the UI thread, there is arguably little benefit using it other than facilitating it to be able to await async methods. This is more to facilitate an event handler to work properly when calling and awaiting *several* async operations.

I.e.

```
private async void Button_Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var firstTask = userService.DoSomethingThatMightTake5SecondsAsync(); // Don't actually name your tasks this! :)
   var secondTask = userService.DoSomethingThatMightTake5SecondsAsync();
   var thirdTask = userService.DoSomethingThatMightTake5SecondsAsync();

   // Do stuff that doesn't rely on those 3 tasks....

   var firstResult = await firstTask;
   // Do something with first task results
   var secondResult = await secondTask;
   // Do something with second task results
   var thirdResult = await thirdTask;
   // Do something with third task results
}
```

Synchronously, those 3 operations would take 15 seconds and whatever else needs to happen that doesn't rely on them would have to wait until they complete. Asynchronously they *could* complete faster, and independent code could execute while they are processing.

Though caution would be needed in the above example with EF as things like the DbContext is not thread safe so kicking off 3 async methods that result in the use of a single DbContext would result in calls to the DbContext by multiple threads. Awaiting them in turn with a UI Thread Sync context is effectively the same as sync calls, only marginally slower. (Overhead of spawning the thread pool threads and waiting for the sync context)

Using `async` should be situational.

Edit: Example with Async vs. Sync:

With a simple WPF form with 2 buttons and a text box (uxEntry). One button for a Synchronous event, one with an Asynchronous event. The textbox will receive focus after one of the buttons is called and you can try typing in it to see if the UI thread is responding:

```
private async void AsyncButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    uxEntry.Focus();
    var result = await DoSomethingAsync();
    MessageBox.Show(result);
}

private void SyncButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    uxEntry.Focus();
    var result = DoSomethingSync();
    MessageBox.Show(result);
}

private async Task<string> DoSomethingAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    });
    return "Done";
}

private string DoSomethingSync()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return "Done";
}
```

In the case where you click the Sync button, the text box won't receive focus or accept input until the 5 seconds is up. In the Async example, it will respond immediately while the async task is running. Async events allow the UI thread to continue responding to events which can make your app feel more responsive, however combining this with EF DbContexts, which are not thread safe, can lead to issues.

Using Async to parallelize operations would be dangerous with code using a single injected DbContext reference, for example:

```
private async void AsyncMultiButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    uxEntry.Focus();

    var task1 = DoSomethingAsync();
    var task2 = DoSomethingAsync();
    var task3 = DoSomethingAsync();

    var result1 = await task1;
    var result2 = await task2;
    var result3 = await task3;

    var message = string.Format("Task1: {0} Task2: {1}  Task3: {2}", result1, result2, result3);

    MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

If `DoSomethingAsync` talked to a repository DbContext those 3 tasks would all start simultaneously, and the DbContext will *not* like that. Depending on the code it can lead to headaches as it appears to work sometimes or in debug environments only to crash with errors at others or in production. The solution would be to await each one in turn:

```
uxEntry.Focus();
var result1 = await DoSomethingAsync();
var result2 = await DoSomethingAsync();
var result3 = await DoSomethingAsync();
```

This would be safe for the DbContext, and the UI would be responsive, however that would now take 15 seconds to complete. It can be tempting to kick them off in parallel, just something to be cautious of when using async. It can be useful for making your application appear more responsive, but be cautious when thinking it can make your application "faster".

Looking at your original code example I don't see a glaring reason why the awaited event handler would still appear to lock up the UI, though that may be some difference between your current code and the example you provided.

Comment: I suggest to add the suffix `Async` to the method `DoSomethingThatMightTake5Seconds`, to comply with the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types).

Comment: Hehe, it's obviously a Pseudo-method, but yeah async methods should suffix Async.

Comment: @StevePy Thank you for answer. I know that for login is unnecessary, but it is only for test. But in future there will be more complex queries. For example getting list of constructions which can user see plus load workers for each construction etc. So query will be more complex with joins. And when login is performed, it is obvious that UI is stucked, with loading construction it will be even worse. 

I want to do what you have in example with  'DoSomethingThatMightTake5SecondsAsync', but how can I do it with EF ?

Comment: @Alox, I've expanded my answer with an example of the Async method and different scenarios to consider between async and sync plus parallel async behavior.